# Excel 2013 Column value determines another columns letter assignment.

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have 5 columns but I need to define column E by column A, If column A has a number that isn't zero in the array, column E should read "Overdue", what formula can I use?

Comment: Please describe your data structure. What is "in the array"?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you want. You want a formula to print "Overdue" in column E, if column A doesn't equal zero.

Placing `=IF(A1=0, "", "Overdue")` in cell E1 should work perfectly. What the formula should do is display nothing if cell A1 equals zero, or "Overdue" if cell A1's value is anything other than zero

The formula will need to be changed for each row, for example, if you want the formula to monitor cell A16, the formula should instead look like `=IF(A16=0, "", "Overdue")`. This can be done automatically by dragging the bottom-right corner of the formula's cell downwards (more information about this can be found [HERE](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2011/08/31/quickly-copy-excel-formula-down/)).